# Is there an equivalent of the IDL dist() function in Python?

Tags: python, idl-programming-language

dist(n) generates a (n x n) matrix of elements. Each element is the straight-line
"distance" from either element [0, 0] or the element just beyond another corner, whichever is closest.

I'm trying to roll the rows and columns to get an array with distances from the centre point, but I'm unsure about how to do this in Python.

In IDL:

```
> print,Shift(dist(5),2,2)

2.82843 2.23607 2.00000 2.23607 2.82843 
2.23607 1.41421 1.00000 1.41421 2.23607 
2.00000 1.00000 0.000000 1.00000 2.00000 
2.23607 1.41421 1.00000 1.41421 2.23607 
2.82843 2.23607 2.00000 2.23607 2.82843
```

Comment: You could def. roll your own with e.g. [np.linalg.norm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy). I'm not aware of a numpy builtin for this, but it's not my field.

Comment: `[[math.hypot(min(i, n-i), min(j, n-j)) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]`

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75793502/2938526) for combined `dist` and `shift`.